# Python MySQLdb: table does not get deleted immediately

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

In my code I try to delete a table from my database (delete_table function). Just right after this, I check if the table has been deleted or not (check_table_from_db function). When I do this, the table gets deleted but check_table_from_db function shows that its not. when I do this process in two different runs (two different programs). The result is correct. 
The following is the code for check_table_from_db:

```
def check_table_from_db(table_name):
    import MySQLdb as mdb
    try:
        exists = False
        con = mdb.connect('localhost', 'user', '123', 'test')
        cur = con.cursor()
        s = "SHOW TABLES LIKE '%s'" % (table_name)
        cur.execute(s)
        exists = (cur.rowcount > 0)
    except mdb.Error, e:
        print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0],e.args[1])
        sys.exit(1)
    finally:        
        if con:
            cur.close()   
            con.close()
        return exists
```

Edit:
Since it has been requested to post the delete_table function, I need to explain what is the general purpose. The delete_table is a function that mimics a SQL injection attack. If the attack is successful, then a table gets deleted from the database (I check this through check_table_from_db). It injects a code in one of the fields in a website. As such the code for delete table is:

```
attack_script = "');DROP TABLE test2;"
_resp = utilities.submit_form(utilities.get_absolute_url(fd.get('action'), main_url), {'uname':'test', 'password':'test', 'cpassword':'test', 'fname':'', 'lname':'', 'age':'', 'major':'', 'university':attack_script}, method=fd.get('method'))
```

Through the submit_form function, I populate the form in the website and I submit. Once submitted, I then check if the table is deleted or not.

Comment: Please also give the code for `delete_table`.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to commit:

```
con.commit()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. Is there a way to commit all previous transactions that took place in previous connection objects (these objects are unknown)?